how to access a List<Map> in flutter
I have the following list:
List<Map> list = [{'id': 5, 'title': 'fdf', 'description': 'fdf'}];

Now, I want to access this list and retrieve, for example, the title value to store it in a variable.
How can I do that?
It is probably very simple, but I got confused.

Does this answer your question? Dart/Flutter How to access element of Map inside a list

Should be as easy as list[0]['title']

You can access title's value like this:
if(list.isNotEmpty){
  print("value = ${list.first["title"]}");
}

or if you list has multiple item you can access like this:
for (var item in list) {
   print("value = ${item["title"]}");
}

and the result would be fdf.
